# how to reference iam role (created in parent stack) in nested stack

Tags: nested, yaml, aws-sam

how to reference the iam role (created in the parent stack) in a nested stack

Here are my yml files for the parent and child stack

I used the !Ref and !GetAtt, none of them are working.

Parent Stack:

```js
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description:
  SAM Template for Nested application resources

Resources:
  Layer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs16.x
      Content:
        S3Bucket: bucketName
        S3Key: Key
      Description: My layer
      LayerName: lambdaLayer
      LicenseInfo: MIT
  SourceIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: source-lambda-iam-omni-agent-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: ''
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: translate-policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - comprehend:DetectDominantLanguage
              - translate:TranslateText
            Resource: '*'
      - PolicyName: invokeLambda-sns-sqs-sm-policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - lambda:InvokeAsync
              - lambda:InvokeFunction
              - sns:Publish
              - iam:ListRoles
              - iam:GetRole
              - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
              - secretsmanager:ListSecrets
              - secretsmanager:UpdateSecret
              - sqs:*
            Resource: '*'
      - PolicyName: sts-policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Resource: '*'
      - PolicyName: write-cloudwatch-logs-policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
              - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource: '*'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaKinesisExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonConnect_FullAccess
      
  config:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location: customerconfig.yml
      Parameters:
        LayerARN: !Ref Layer
        IAMRole: !Ref SourceIAMRole
    DependsOn:
      - Layer
      - SourceIAMRole
```

I did pass the IAM role to the nested stack in the parameter as you can see above in the parent stack. Now I need to pass the ARN created in the parent stack to child (nested) stack

Child stack (Nested)

```js
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description:
  Start from scratch starter project

Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs16.x
    Timeout: 15
    CodeUri: ./
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-005941cb59bd3c74e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-083b8c9bc31cefb69
          - subnet-0f77f5b03c7fc1bc7
    Layers:
      - !Ref LayerARN
    MemorySize: 128

Parameters:
  LayerARN:
    Type: String
  IAMRole:
    Type: String
    
Resources:
  helloFromLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Role: !GetAtt IAMRole.Arn
      Handler: api/getapplicationconfig.handler
      Description: A Lambda function that returns a static string.
```

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to make it work,

While passing the parameters to nested stack, for the IAM role we will use
!GetAtt SourceIAMRole.Arn.

```js
config:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location: customerconfig.yml
      Parameters:
        LayerARN: !Ref Layer
        IAMRole: !GetAtt SourceIAMRole.Arn
```